# iPhone - a question about navigationControllers and viewController

Tags: iphone

I have a project based on Xcode's NavigationController template. This template has a navigationController and a RootViewController.

From inside this RootViewController I push a view and this view pushes a third view. Something like:

NavigationController >> RootViewController >> ViewController 1 >>  ViewController 2

Now, from ViewController2 I want to access the navigationController and the navigationController.toolbar.

I know that every viewController has the navigationController property but my question do I have to do something when I push a new viewController so this variable (on the view that is being pushed) will have a valid reference to the correct ViewController or all pushed views will always have a valid reference to the navigationController?

The reason for my question is that I am trying to access the navigationController.toolbar, to make it invisible, and I am having no result.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try `-[UINavigationController setToolbarHidden:animated:]` to hide the toolbar instead:

```
[self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:YES animated:YES];
```

This has always worked for me no matter how deep in the navigation stack my view controller was.

---

In the entire navigation stack of one `UINavigationController` object, every view controller's `navigationController` property has the same value.

Answer (score 1):

The navController is like a box that contains the viewControllers within, with the last one to be pushed shown to the user until it is popped off, when the one below it will come to life again.

This means you can rely on the navController instance always being available from within a controller that was pushed by the navController.

Comment: It's more like a stack, actually. :)

Comment: I know, I was just trying to convey that the navController "contains" the viewControllers.

Comment: I love the box analogy thanks, that clears a lot. Seriously, Apple should hire you to write documentation. :D